# Silverlight (like) Validation in Windows Form app

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, .net-3.5

I need to Enable/Disable my SAVE button in real time based on data in my fields.

Is the below an acceptable way on accomplishing this?  It feels wrong but I don't know how else I could accomplish this.

Each User Control(*CRUD Form*) has a `BackgroundWorker` and the following related methods;

- `StartBGWorker()`
- `StopBGWorker()`
- `RequiredFieldsValid()`

There purpose is self-explanatory, I hope.  The process goes in such a way that when a User clicks NEW or EDIT it places a call to `StartBGWorker()` which creates a new `BackgroundWorker` and calls `RunDataASync()` for it.  The `DoWork()` method of the BGWorker looks like this:

```
    void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ucNavDiagnosis.btnSave.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(e.UserState);
    }

    void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {            
        while (true)
        {                
            bgWorker.ReportProgress(0, RequiredFieldsValid());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

private bool RequiredFieldsValid()
{
    // TODO: Add other required fields
    return (!memAllergies.Text.Equals(string.Empty));
}
```

This works but feels "bush-league."  Anyway, when the User clicks SAVE or CANCEL a call to `StopBGWorker()` is placed which `Disposes` the worker.

As a further disclaimer, this app does not currently use binding.  It's a long explanation but that's that, as they say.

Comment: It might help if you clarify what your question is.

Comment: @Lucas B: My apologies, I thought it was apparent but I see now how it could not have been.  Is that better?  Thanks for speaking up!

Comment: There for sure is a reason: why don't you check RequiredFieldsValid() whenever an input in one of the controls becomes valid?

Comment: @Mario The Spoon: You mean hook into the validating event for all controls on a given Form?

Comment: Yeah, I assume that is why it's called validating.. (to be honest, I thought to ptach something into LostFocus , but Validating sounds like the solution). I goe with Lucas B and wait until the user is done with input. If you absolutely need to, you can hook something in the key-up events or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the validating events to update the enabled status of your save button?!!

```
protected virtual void MyTextBox_OnValidating(CancelEventArgs e)
{
     this.SaveButton.Enabled = (Validate(MyTextBox));
}
```

As well, if you are doing validation, I highly recommend looking into [MS enterprise library validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650131.aspx) to handle informing the user of input errors.  Also, check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951078.aspx).

Comment: It is simply checking the fields for data.  Very simplistic but all we require at this point.  No SProcs and no attempted saves.  I added an example of the `RequiredFieldsValid()` method.

Comment: Also, maybe I am being thick but neither of your links solutions solves my "on the fly" issue, no?

Comment: @refracted what does "on the fly" mean?  Are you trying to keep the UI responsive, or something else?

Comment: Basically, as they type...if what they type makes the required fields valid I want it to Enable the Save button and vice versa.

Comment: I would not recommend validating while the user is providing input, only after the control loses focus; otherwise the user experience will be horrible.

Comment: Instead, when they click save, highlight for them what is not valid and where.  The MS enterprise library is a solid framework for these types of interactions

Comment: :-)  Thank you Lucas for the effort.  Unfortunately that is what I already have implemented and it is not enough for the business.  They don't want to even be able to click Save until the form is Valid...Think the way Silverlight tends to do it.

Comment: @refracted Somehow I missed that you wanted to enable/disable the save button.  I have updated my answer.